# AWK user-defined function - a new syntax?

Tags: awk, gawk

When looking for a quick way of right trimming a text string, I found the following wiki page:

[Wiki trimming page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimming_%28computer_programming%29)

In the chapter about AWK it gives 2 sets of examples:

```
ltrim(v) = gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", v)

rtrim(v) = gsub(/[ \t]+$/, "", v)

trim(v)  = ltrim(v); rtrim(v)
```

or

```
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t]+/, "", s); return s }

function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t]+$/, "", s); return s }

function trim(s)  { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }
```

The lower example is entirely familiar and works fine, but the first example looks different to anything I have seen in 20 years of AWK programming. It looks like a really useful quick way to define and use a function in one line. I can't get this syntax to work in GNU Awk 3.1.5 - so is it something which was introduced in a more recent version?

I would be grateful of a real working example if anyone is familiar with this syntax.

Comment: the first example is just pseudo-code. you have to use the second form for it to be legal awk-syntax. Should have been convenient though :-)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this example is just wrong. 
The syntax

`identifier(parameter) = ...`

doesn't work with none of the variants I've tested: *GNU awk* (3, 4 - the latest for the moment), *AT&T Bell's awk* and *mawk*.

Just like calling an undefined function produces an error as expected as well.

Perhaps the author wanted only to illustrate the idea with pseudo-code?

Comment: I see - yes that makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to test.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the first set of examples doesn't define a function but just tells that the (missing) `ltrim(s)` function can be replaced by `gsub(/^[ \t]+/, "", v)`, etc.

gsub is unnecessary by the way, sub would be enough like it is in the function alternative.

Comment: Yes, on a second read, I think that your understanding is correct. Often we're too literal :)